# WinHttpConnect does not return error on bad URL

Tags: winhttp

I have been using WinHTTP API functions from PowerBuilder 10 and it works really well except that the WinHttpConnect function does not return an error when the URL is bad. If I pass an empty string for ServerName then the returned handle is zero but GetLastError is zero as well.

If I am reading the documentation correctly, the returned handle should be zero if the ServerName is bad and there should be an error code from

I am currently on Windows 8.1 but I have seen this on XP and 7.